# how to solve this subTotal situation?

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I had a context's state that have an array with some objects inside of him. the objects are something like

```
state[
 {
   name: name,
   value: 200,
   unit: 2
  },
 {
  name: othername,
  value: 50,
  unit: 1
 }]
```

I need to multiply the value with the units and then sum with the other objects.

I tried to use

```
useEffect(()=>{
 state.items.map((each) => {
  return setSubtotal( previousValue => previousValue + each.unit * Number(each.price));
 },[state])
```

it works for sum, but when i remove some object of the state, i dont know what i have to do to subtract the value. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you, I put a `reducer` on it

```
const subTotal = state.items.reduce((previousValue , each) => each.unit * Number(each.price) + previousValue , 0); 

 useEffect(()=>{
    setSubtotal( subTotal );
 },[subTotal])
```